# How to have multiple columns for a single field in view

Tags: views

I created a content type with image field which accepts unlimited values. Now, I have 25 images uploaded to the field. I created a page view. I selected the image field. For the view settings, I selected **Grid** format > **Number of column**: 2.

When I go to views page, I expected to see 2 columns on the page views but I did not. How can I make sure I can see only 2 columns of images in the views page when I set number of columns equal 2 in **Grid** setting?

Comment: do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure field in **Views** there is an option  **Display all values in the same row**  under **Multiple field settings**  uncheck that option. By doing this each image will display in separate column.